# Sum elements of list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to sum element of a list like this:

```
sum([1,[2,3],4],S).
```

I used that but I have a problem:

```
sum([],0).
sum([T|R],M) :- sum(R,S), M is T+S.
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: is/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2,3]' (a list) ("x" must hold one character)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't add T if T is a list. You could easily solve using `is_list/1` that succeds if T is a list:

```
sum([],0).
sum([T|R],M) :- (is_list(T) -> sum(T,N1),sum(R,S), M is N1+S
                 ; sum(R,S), M is T+S ).
```

Examples:

```
?- sum([1,[2,3],4],S).
S = 10.

?- sum([1,2,3,4],S).
S = 10.

?- sum([1,[2],[3],4],S).
S = 10.

?- sum([1,[[2],[3]],4],S).
S = 10.
```

A better approach would be using CLPFD:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sum([],0).
sum([[]],0).
sum([T|R],M) :- (is_list(T) -> sum(T,N1),sum(R,S), M #= N1+S
                 ; sum(R,S), M #= T+S ).
```

Now you can query more general questions like:

```
?- sum(L,N).
L = [],
N = 0 ;
L = [[]],
N = 0 ;
L = [N],
N in inf..sup ;
L = [N, []],
N in inf..sup ;
L = [_1836, _1842],
_1836+_1842#=N ;
L = [_1842, _1848, []],
_1842+_1848#=N ;
L = [_2142, _2148, _2154],
_2142+_2192#=N,
_2148+_2154#=_2192 ;
L = [_2148, _2154, _2160, []],
_2148+_2204#=N,
_2154+_2160#=_2204 ;
L = [_2448, _2454, _2460, _2466],
_2448+_2504#=N,
_2454+_2528#=_2504,
_2460+_2466#=_2528 ;
```

and goes on...

Comment: The answers to your last query are incomplete. For one, `sum([[]],0)` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
% Old code, with vars renamed:
%sum([], 0).
%sum([Num|Tail], TotalSum) :- sum(Tail, TailSum), TotalSum is Num + TailSum.

% New code:
sum([], 0).
sum([Elem|Tail], TotalSum) :- 
    sum(Elem, ElemSum),
    sum(Tail, TailSum),
    TotalSum is ElemSum + TailSum.
sum(Num, Num).
```

Demo: http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/cmzcsXrJ.pl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatten/2 plus foldl/4 or sum_list/2 library predicates in Swi-Prolog:

```
% flatten/2 + foldl/4 based implementation
sum_nested_list(List, Sum) :-
    flatten(List, Flat),
    foldl(plus, Flat, 0, Sum).

% flatten/2 + sum_list/2 based implementation
sum_nested_list(List, Sum) :-
    flatten(List, Flat),
    sum_list(Flat, Sum).
```